# Return matching value from substring in a list against dictionary containing substring

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries like below.

```
[{'cvid': '642', 'switch': '015ABC003999FR', 'uni': '5'},
 {'cvid': '523', 'switch': '017ABC001230FR', 'uni': '5'},
 {'cvid': '43', 'switch': '017ABC001231FR', 'uni': '2'},
 {'cvid': '45', 'switch': '500ABC005437FR', 'uni': '3'}]
```

I also have a list containing values like below.

```
[['000015ABC003999CIRC'], ['000017ABC001230CIRC'], ['000017ABC001231CIRC'], ['000015ABC000249CIRC'], ['000500ABC005437CIRC']]
```

I'd like be able to extract a substring from the {'switch':'015ABC003999FR'} value and have the value 000015ABC003999CIRC returned and appended to that same dictionary as {'circ':'000015ABC003999CIRC'}.

I haven't been able to find an example close to that scenario. Is it possible to do like a regex for 015ABC003999 of the dictionary then also match on a regex of the list? I think another option would be to just create the value adding zeroes to the front and replacing the FR with CIRC but I'd rather match to the list as a sort of verification.

I'd then use the dictionary to populate configurations sort of like below

```
print('cfm service delete service ' + dic['switch'])
print('cfm mep create service ' + dic['circ'] + ' port ' +  dic['uni'] + ' type up vlan ' +  dic['cvid'] + ' mepid 3')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but I'd rather match to the list as a sort of verification."?

Comment: What is the expected ouput?

Comment: In case the device I'm creating the dictionary from has extra circuits. The list is sort of like a known good I guess. Also added the end goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate over both in two for loops, it looks like you need to remove the last two characters of the `switch` values before checking for a substring using `in`:

```
import json

data = [
          {
            "cvid": "642",
            "switch": "015ABC003999FR",
            "uni": "5"
          },
          {
            "cvid": "523",
            "switch": "017ABC001230FR",
            "uni": "5"
          },
          {
            "cvid": "43",
            "switch": "017ABC001231FR",
            "uni": "2"
          },
          {
            "cvid": "45",
            "switch": "500ABC005437FR",
            "uni": "3"
          }
        ]

lst = [['000015ABC003999CIRC'], ['000017ABC001230CIRC'], ['000017ABC001231CIRC'],
      ['000015ABC000249CIRC'], ['000500ABC005437CIRC']]

for d in data:
  switch_val_without_last_2_ch = d["switch"][:-2]
  for sub_lst in lst:
    val = sub_lst[0]
    if switch_val_without_last_2_ch in val:
      d["circ"] = val
      break

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, sort_keys=False))

for dic in data:
  print(f'cfm service delete service {dic["switch"]}')
  print(f'cfm mep create service {dic["circ"]} port {dic["uni"]} type up vlan {dic["cvid"]} mepid 3')
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "cvid": "642",
    "switch": "015ABC003999FR",
    "uni": "5",
    "circ": "000015ABC003999CIRC"
  },
  {
    "cvid": "523",
    "switch": "017ABC001230FR",
    "uni": "5",
    "circ": "000017ABC001230CIRC"
  },
  {
    "cvid": "43",
    "switch": "017ABC001231FR",
    "uni": "2",
    "circ": "000017ABC001231CIRC"
  },
  {
    "cvid": "45",
    "switch": "500ABC005437FR",
    "uni": "3",
    "circ": "000500ABC005437CIRC"
  }
]
cfm service delete service 015ABC003999FR
cfm mep create service 000015ABC003999CIRC port 5 type up vlan 642 mepid 3
cfm service delete service 017ABC001230FR
cfm mep create service 000017ABC001230CIRC port 5 type up vlan 523 mepid 3
cfm service delete service 017ABC001231FR
cfm mep create service 000017ABC001231CIRC port 2 type up vlan 43 mepid 3
cfm service delete service 500ABC005437FR
cfm mep create service 000500ABC005437CIRC port 3 type up vlan 45 mepid 3
```

Try it on **[repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/VeneratedDualDeskscan#main.py)**